# WPFToolkit AutoCompleteBox Property Text is not updated after select item

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpftoolkit

After select an item from list, the text property of autocombobox is not updatet.

XAML:

```
<toolkit:AutoCompleteBox Name="acbAuftragsnummer" >
```

Code Behind:

```
acbAuftragsnummer.ItemsSource = list; // String List that contains proposals
string text = acbAuftragsnummer.Text; // Contains only entered text, but not selected text from proposal list
```

Aditional Information:
I want to AutoCompleteBox only making suggestions if entered text has at least3 chars. So I had an TextChanged EventHandler like this:

```
        private void acbAuftragsnummer_TextChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (acbAuftragsnummer.Text.Length > 2)
        {
            acbAuftragsnummer.ItemsSource = _vorschlaegeAuftragsnummerList.Where(o => o.StartsWith(acbAuftragsnummer.Text)).Take(10);
        }
    }
```

This also updates the ItemsSource if I pick some element from the list. This seems to lead to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the TextChanged Eventhandler and added list to AutoCompleteBox only once (if page loaded). Then I used MinimumPrefixLength="3" to acheive my requirements.

Comment: I was about to suggest this myself but I see you already found your own answer.  The only snag to this would be if you wish to refer to a database of items that you do not wish to pull all entries back first. The problem comes because you are changing the source, so it can't refer to the auto-complete item that was selected and leaves Text as being what was entered.

Comment: You're right. This is actually just a work-around, since now I have to load the full list from database at the beginning. I can't just take a subset of list entries depending on the first letters entred in AutoComboBox. But it works for me at the moment.

Comment: Do you want me to investigate an alternative or are you happy to accept that ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you limited the text box to only entries in the source collection ? I would suspect not this any value is allowed and the previous text would be valid even if null

Comment: No, I can't limit the text to only list entries. Other values must be allowed too. But if I select a text from the list, I need the full text of that item, not the text I've entered (wich makes sence, if you want to use autocomplete).

Comment: Yeah I get your meaning. I haven't used the autocomplete box in a long time as I've been on the extended toolkit for some time. Do you have a quick sample project and I'll tweak it for you?

Comment: I take it you managed to either resolve this now or no long persuing this route?

Comment: Here I put a test-project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/a22fay34mays0qs/AutoCompleteBoxExample.zip?dl=0